# How to change a default name of the folder that CRM creates to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm completely new to Sharepoint so keep that in mind when answering or assuming things.

Anyways, we have a CRM 2015 Online Update 1 and Sharepoint Online and those are integrated (not by me). Now when an end-user goes to Account -> Documents the CRM will automatically ask if the user wants to create a folder to Sharepoint. That's fine, but naming convention seems to be "AccountName_AccountGuid". We would like to change that to "AccountName_OurOwnID" where OurOwnID is a custom field in CRM that is unique for every account.

So my question is how would one do this?

EDIT: All I can think of now is to create a plugin that'll be launched when ever a sharepointdocumentlocation entity is created and basically create a new folder with wanted name and then delete the original folder in Sharepoint and then connect the new folder with sharepointdocumentlocation.

Sub-question: Is there a way to tell CRM to stop asking if the user wants to create a new folder? In my case it's unwanted feature but since it is there at least we should make sure that names of the folders will be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder name with the guid is default behavior which cannot be altered.

If you want to develop a plugin, look at this post: https://crmconsultancy.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/crm-2011-integration-with-sharepoint-custom-document-management/

Keep in mind, if you want to create objects in SharePoint from CRM online you have two options:

- Add the SharePoint.Client assembly with ILMerge. Officialy this is not supported.
- Or use the rest endpoint of SharePoint. This is an interesting post to read: https://bingsoft.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/crm-online-to-sharepoint-online-integration-using-rest-and-adfs/

Comment: And for autocreating of SharePoint folders:
http://crmbook.powerobjects.com/system-administration/sharepoint-document-management/beyond-basic-integration/bulk-creating-sharepoint-folders-and-automatic-integration-with-dynamics-crm/

Comment: Cheers. Very helpful links and I was able to pull out a simple plugin that did the trick. For future visitors I'd like to add this link that I relied on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx